# C++ boolean logic error possibly caused by if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean-logic

Here is an extremely simplified version of a section of code that I am having trouble with.

```
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
int time = 50;
int steps = 1000;
double Tol = 0.1;
bool crossRes = false;
bool doNext = true;

for (int i=0; i<steps; i++) {

//a lot of operations are done here, I will leave out the details, the only
//important things are that "dif" is calculated each time and doNext either
//stays true or is switched to false

    if (doNext = true) {
        if (dif <= Tol) count++;
        if (count >= time) {
            i = steps+1;
            crossRes = true;
        }
    }
}

    if (crossRes = true) {
        printf("Nothing in this loop should happen if dif is always > Tol 
               because count should never increment in that case, right?");
    }
```

My issue is that every time it gets done with the for loop, it executes the statements inside the "if (crossRes = true)" brackets even if count is never incremented.

Comment: Its == true. = assigns a value instead of comparing it

Comment: Please don't edit the corrected code into your question. That makes it impossible to see what the problem was, and causes the answers not to make sense. I'm going to revert your edit.

Answer (score 5):

You've made a common (and quite frustrating) mistake:

```
if (crossRes = true) {
```

This line assigns `crossRes` to `true` and returns `true`. You're looking to *compare* `crossRes` with `true`, which means you need another equals sign:

```
if (crossRes == true) {
```

Or more concisely:

```
if (crossRes) {
```

Comment: I think `if (crossRes) {` is definitely the best thing to use here. `<boolean varaible> == true` is very redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I stand corrected:

```
if (crossRes)
```

<del>You wouldn't have this problem if your condition was 

    if (true = crossRes) 

because it wouldn't compile.

`crossRes = true` always evaluates to `true` because it's an assignment, to `true`.

You want `crossRes == true`:

    if (crossRes == true) {
        printf("Nothing in this loop should happen if dif is always > Tol 
               because count should never increment in that case, right?");
    }</del>

Comment: Why not `if ((crossRes == true) == true)`? Recursive redundancy yay!

Comment: No, you want `if (crossRes)`. And so-called "Yoda conditions" like `if (42 == x)` can avoid ==/= problems, but IMHO they're ugly.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment, `==` is equality comparison.  You want:

```
if (crossRes == true) {
```

You make the same mistake here:

```
if (doNext = true) { // Bad code
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here have told you the problem. Often your compiler will warn you but a way to ensure that you do not do this is to put the constant term on the left

```
 true == crossRes
```

that way you get a compiler error instead of a warning and so it can't escape unnoticed since

```
 true = crossRes
```

wont compile.

Comment: I'd always wondered why some people put constants on the left... it looks weird to me, but this is a good explanation.

Comment: Also known as a "yoda condition"

Answer (score 1):

First, although a number of people have pointed to the problem with `if (crossRes = true)`, for some reason they haven't (yet, anyway) pointed to the same problem with `if (doNext = true)`.

I'll stick to pointing out that you really want `if (crossRes)` rather than `if (crossRes == true)` (or even `if (true == crossRes)`).

The first reason is that it avoids running into the same problem from a simple typo.

The second is that the result of the comparison is a `bool` -- so if `if (crossRes==true)` is necessary, you probably need `if (((((crossRes == true) == true) == true) == true)` just to be sure (maybe a few more -- you never know). This would, of course, be utterly silly -- you're starting with a `bool`, so you don't need a comparison to get a `bool`.

I'd also note for the record, that if you insist on doing a comparison at all, you should almost always use `if (x != false)` rather than `if (x == true)`. Though it doesn't really apply in C++, in old C that doesn't have an actual Boolean type, any integer type can be used -- but in this case, a comparison to `true` can give incorrect results. At least normally, `false` will be 0 and `true` will be 1 -- but when tested, *any* non-zero value will count as equivalent to `true`. For example:

```
int x = 10;

if (x)    // taken

if (x == true) // not taken, but should be.
```

If you're not starting with a Boolean value as you are here, then the `if (<constant> <comparison> <variable>)`  makes sense and is (IMO) preferred. But when you're starting with a Boolean value anyway, just use it; don't do a comparison to produce another of the same.

Comment: If you insist on doing a comparison at all, you should *get over it*. Comparing values for equality or inequality to `true` or `false` is unnecessary and potentially dangerous. Just write `if (x)` or `if (!x)`. See [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/136908/33478) and [my answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/136933/33478).